# how to make responsive and to fit image correctly without weird stretching resize in banner image

Tags: css

the problem is simple if you check this website: [my demo website here](https://zealous-shirley-aa4edf.netlify.app/) on mobile,

you will see image looks weird, is there a way to prevent it?

also in desktop mode happens the same, i am newbie in css and responsive design. thank you

all the images are on 4160x3120 px

[image: example of problem]

[image: desktop example]

css code:

```
 <style>

        html,
        body {
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        
        #slider {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-size: cover;
        }
        
        #slider * {
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
          height: 100% !important;
          width: 100% !important;
        }

        .centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


        </style>
```

html code:

```
<div id="slider" class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s">
       
       
        <img src="images/home-bg-slideshow1.jpg">
        <img src="images/home-bg-slideshow35.jpg">
        <img src="images/home-bg-slideshow15.jpg">
        <img src="images/home-bg-slideshow16.jpg">
        
        <div class="wow fadeInUp centered" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="z-index: 800;
        font-weight: 1000;font-size: 50px;color: #f7b600;"></div>
      </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-size: cover;
```

Your code `background-size: 100% 100%;` means that you want your image to fit both width and height, which is not the case, you want your image to fit its content in the given dimensions. `100%` image size is applied only when you don't care about the image height/width ratio being respected

Answer (score 1):

You can set fixed height to your image and add object-fit: cover to prevent picture from distortion.